# Получить удаленно все виртуальные директории IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, visual-studio-2017

Скачал из Nuget последнюю версию `Microsoft.Web.Administration` и пытаюсь достучаться до IIS на сервере с Win Server 2008 выполнив метод `ServerManager.OpenRemote("ServerName");` , но почему-то метод ничего не возвращает.

Если попытаться перечислить сайты, то получаю ошибку "DCOM is UNSUPPORTED"

Может быть есть какие-то тонкости работы с этой библиотекой?

Какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: Возможно может помочь msdn: [Error: Unable to initiate DCOM communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fex01a8.aspx)

Comment: Альтернатива через WMI, но скорее всего там тоже DCOM задействовано.

Comment: WMI как раз заработал.

Comment: Чего в WMI нету такого, что есть в NuGet? Или задача имеенно NuGet юзать?

Comment: @nick_n_a, можно и WMI, но я попробовал использовать класс, так как он интуитивно понятен, но похоже не судьба.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось вот такое решение через WMI:

```
   private static List<ReplaceTemplate> GetReplaceList(string server,string siteName)
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        var scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{server}\root\MicrosoftIISv2", options);
        scope.Connect();
        ObjectQuery query2 = new ObjectQuery($"SELECT * FROM IIsWebServerSetting WHERE ServerComment=\"{siteName}\"");
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM IIsWebVirtualDirSetting");
        ManagementObjectSearcher shareSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectSearcher webSiteSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query2);
        //Получаем ServerComment для нужного сайта. Это поле нужо, что бы получить все директории этого сайта
        var webSitename = webSiteSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Single(x => x["ServerComment"].ToString() == siteName)["Name"] + "/";
        var result = shareSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
            .Where(x => x["Name"].ToString().StartsWith(webSitename)).ToList();
            //Физический путь и название виртуальной директории.
        return result.Select(x => new ReplaceTemplate(x["Path"].ToString(), x["Name"].ToString().Split('/').Last())).ToList();
    }
```